# How can I get search result from multi table in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in Mysql
order table:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+
| ID | Buyer name  | Shipping address |
+----+-------------+------------------+
|  1 | J. Hart     | address1         |
|  2 | D. Kenny    | address2         |
|  3 | O. Martin   | address3         |
|  4 | P. Escudero | address4         |
+----+-------------+------------------+
```

order detail table:

```
+----+----------+------------+-------+-------+
| ID | Order ID | Item name  | price | quant |
+----+----------+------------+-------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | hat        | 2.6   |     2 |
|  2 |        1 | jacket     | 3.7   |     1 |
|  3 |        2 | jeen       | 3.5   |    10 |
|  4 |        3 | Tshirt     | 7.2   |     1 |
|  5 |        3 | necklace   | 2.7   |     5 |
|  6 |        4 | hat        | 2.6   |    12 |
+----+----------+------------+-------+-------+
```

In the view file(PHP), I'll show all information in "order table".
When I type a keyword and submit form, results will be show everything like keyword in 2 tables.
Example: when I type : "ha" or "HA" or "Ha" or some thing like that, result will be show 2 records:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+
| ID | Buyer Name  | Shipping address |
+----+-------------+------------------+
|  1 | J. Hart     | address1         |
|  4 | P. Escudero | address4         |
+----+-------------+------------------+
```

You can see, "ha" exist in Buyer Name: "J. Hart" and item "hat" of Order 1 and 4
How can I get it by Mysql or PHP? Every one have a solution? Please! Many thanks for you.

Comment: Hi @Alex , how can you fix my table. I tried but I can format it

Comment: when you in edit mode just select text block and click on `{}` button in edit panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select b.`Buyer name`,o.`Item name` from buyer b, order o 
    where  b.`Buyer name` like '%ha%' or o.`Item name` like '%ha%';
```